# Node Mongoose not saving post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to get node to save a post request to my MongoDB, I am not getting any errors thrown, but nothing is being stored in the database.

modules.js

```
var mongoose      = require ( 'mongoose' ),
Schema        = mongoose.Schema,
modulesSchema = new Schema (
    {
        ModuleID: Number,
        ModuleName: String,
        ModuleLeader: String
    }, { _id: false }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model ( 'Module', modulesSchema );
```

server.js

```
var express    = require ( 'express' ),
    app        = express (),
    bodyParser = require ( 'body-parser' ),
    jwt        = require ( 'jsonwebtoken' ),
    mongoose   = require ( 'mongoose' ),
    mongoUri   = 'mongodb://feedbacker:feedbacker@ds011472.mlab.com:11472/feedbacker';
    secretKey  = 'f33db3ck4r';

// database in the cloud
mongoose.connect (
    mongoUri, function ( error )
    {
        if ( error )
        {
            console.error ( 'Mongoose Error! Error: ', error );
        }
    }
);

// bodyparser to read and post json data
app.use ( bodyParser.urlencoded ( { extended: true } ) );
app.use ( bodyParser.json () );

// load models
var User    = require ( './models/user' ),
    Student = require ( './models/student' ),
    Module  = require ( './models/modules' );

router.route('/module').post(function(req, res) {
    var module = new Module();
    module.ModuleID = req.body.moduleID;
    module.ModuleName = req.body.moduleName;
    module.ModuleLeader = req.body.moduleLeader;

    module.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Module Created!' });
    });
});
// register router
app.use ( '/api', router );
```

I cut out a chunk of the server.js as most of it is middleware and other routes going on that does not affect this.

I have used Postman to test this, and i do not get the res.json message.
But if i change the routing too:

```
router.route('/module').post(function(req, res) {
var module = new Module();
module.ModuleID = req.body.moduleID;
module.ModuleName = req.body.moduleName;
module.ModuleLeader = req.body.moduleLeader;

module.save(function(err) {
    if (err)

    res.json({ message: 'Module Created!' });
});
});
```

This is removing the following line:

```
return res.send(err);
```

This will indeed send a response 'Module Created!' ... so any reason why this is happening? Because i am getting no errors anywhere and nothing being stored. And yes my database details are setup correctly

Any help apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

ah turns out using _id false doesn't go down to well, i changed my model to:

```
var mongoose      = require ( 'mongoose' ),
    Schema        = mongoose.Schema,
    modulesSchema = new Schema (
        {
            _id: Number,
            moduleName: String,
            moduleLeader: String
        }
    );

module.exports = mongoose.model ( 'Module', modulesSchema );
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyy am not sure but you are returning res.json({ message: 'Module Created!' }) if there is error

```
module.save(function(err) {
    if (err)

    res.json({ message: 'Module Created!' });
```

});
So try this once after correting this may be it works...
And also try to run like this to check what respoonse u are getting

```
module.save(function(err,data) {
    if (err){
     console.log("Error",err)
     return
    }
    console.log(data)
    res.json({ message: 'Module Created!' });
 });
```